# Visual Studio 2013 Disable Intellisense for AngularJs Tags

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, intellisense

Is it possible to remove/disable only the "ng-" Intellisense in HTML Editor from Visual Studio?

Because of hard Performance problems, the intellisense is very slow.

When I've activated the "list members" for HTML Editor and when I type "ng-" I've to wait about 3-5 seconds until the popup menue comes up and the editor hangs completly. 
When I deactivate "list members" everything works fine but then I've no Intellisense for css classes any more and that more usefull than autocomplete for some ng directives.

I only use Bootstrap, font-awesome and animate.css from Angular - nothing really big.

(I've also installed resharper 9.1.x and Web Essentials and when I deactivate both the problem stays - its a problem with the VS-Intellisense)

Comment: Please vote here for this feature: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/12301959-provide-an-option-in-the-html-editor-to-disable-an